# I can't Pass custom props to "export default"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for the noob question, i'm completely new to this, so here it goes:
I'm practicing react and normally when i do something like:

```
var Person = function(props){
return(
<h1>Hi, {props.name}</h1>
);
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Person name="Jon"/>,
document.getElementById("app")
);
```

i would see: "Hi, Jon"

but the thing is, i'm now using create-react-app and there instead of ReactDOM.render(), i just have:

```
export default Person;
```

and i don't know how to inject my props into "Person" in order to see "Hi, Jon"
i tried guessing solutions like:

```
export default Person(name:'Jon');
```

or things like that but of course it doesn't work.
I dont have enough information to google the right question even though i tried a lot of possibilities but couldn't find any solution. so i hope someone would help/educate me here.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you have different components you must use in parrent component:

```
import Person from './Person';

ReactDOM.render(<Person name="Jon"/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

and in child it must be smth like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Person extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      };
render() {
  return(
  <h1>Hi, {props.name}</h1>
  );
}

export default Person;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass by this way i don't know its correct but it worked for me

```
const test = {
    myValue(props){
        return props.yourValue
    }
}
```